# My app have alarm ringing functionality. unfortunately sometimes alarm ringing with bit time delay(time delay varies at different time)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Some times alarm rings with a delay ,and the delay varies from 1 minute to 5 minute.i have removed the seconds value from the time which is passed to alarm manager still the time delay exist.

```
when (selectedRepeat!!.id) {
        Repeat.Never.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = 0L
        }
        Repeat.Daily.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
        }
        Repeat.Weekly.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 7
        }
        Repeat.Monthly.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = Utils.getMonthDuration()
        }
        Repeat.HalfYearly.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = 15552000000L
        }
        Repeat.Annually.Id -> {
            val calendar = GregorianCalendar()
            alarmInterval = if (calendar.isLeapYear(Calendar.YEAR)) {
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 366
            } else {
                AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 365
            }
        }
        Repeat.CustomDays.Id -> {
            alarmInterval = AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY
        }
    }

    val operation =
        PendingIntent.getActivity(
            baseContext,
            requestCode,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        )
    val alarmManager: AlarmManager = baseContext.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager



    val calendar = selectedDate
 alarmManager.setRepeating(
        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        alarmTime,
        alarmInterval,
        operation
    )
```

Comment: `AlarmManager#setRepeating()` hasn't been exact since at least KitKat. You should have a look at the docs for [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

Comment: setExact or setExact while idle methods are required as already mentioned above setRepeating is not exact

Comment: Have you tried `setExact`?

Comment: yes tried ,it working properly with set exact but i have to repeat these alarm,is there any option to add repeat with set exact